# how to run command in ssh-keygen.exe with java

Tags: java, ssh, command

I am able to run ssh-keygen with code below, but i still unclear on how to execute command inside SSH-keygen.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.exec.CommandLine;
import org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor;
import org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteWatchdog;


public class ApacheRunSSHKEygen {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    try {

//        String line = "AcroRd32.exe /p /h " + file.getAbsolutePath();
    String line = "C:\\ExecuteSSH\\ssh-keygen.exe -N";
    CommandLine cmdLine = CommandLine.parse(line);
    DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();

    //watchdog
    executor.setExitValue(1);
    ExecuteWatchdog watchdog = new ExecuteWatchdog(60000);
    executor.setWatchdog(watchdog);

    int exitValue = executor.execute(cmdLine);
    }

    catch (Exception exc){

       System.out.println("error" + exc);/*handle exception*/} 
    }


}
```

the output is :

> ssh-keygen: option requires an argument -- N
>
> usage: ssh-keygen [options]
>
> Options:
>
> -a trials   Number of trials for screening DH-GEX  moduli.
>
> -B          Show bubblebabble digest of key file.
>
> -b bits     Number of bits in the key to create.
>
> ....... .......
>
> -y          Read private key file and print public key.

if the  code and command is right, the output after that should prompted for passphrase. like below

> Generating public/private rsa key pair.
>
> Enter file in which to save the key
>   (/cygdrive/c/Users/USER/.ssh/id_rsa):
>
> Enter passphrase:

Comment: guys, at least can i have the link direction document to how to run cmd command line. thanks :)

Comment: The output is telling what you did wrong:  The `-N` option must be followed by an argument.  If you want the command to prompt for a passphrase, don't include -N at all.

Comment: thanks VGR, but why when i run the ssh-keygen.exe, it freeze after 

Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/cygdrive/c/Users/USER/.ssh/id_rsa):

any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell is complaining that you didn't pass a passphrase with the "-N" argument.  You can add a passphrase and file to your command to make it work correctly, something like this

```
String line = "C:\\ExecuteSSH\\ssh-keygen.exe -N \"my_passphrase_is_poopydiapers\" -f /tmp/mykey";
```

You could also leave the "-N" off and just exec ssh-keygen.exe with no arguments to get the output you said you expected in your post.  However, then you'd have to feed the passphrase and file in to `DefaultExecutor` through STDIN, which would be much more difficult than specifying that info on the commandline.

Comment: @user3117780 Please accept this answer if it is the best one.

Comment: Ireeder thank you it work for me. Thanks for everyone help. ok now i already accept your answer.